# What is this item?

Tags: identification, french-revolution, french-empire

I bought this thing (medallion? military decoration? jewelry? something else?) just because I've become obsessed with figuring out what this broken thing is.  Any ideas?

The medallion is about 3 inches in diameter.  I'm guessing French only because the color arrangements mimics the French cockade, but then the crown doesn't seem to fit from a historic perspective.  In case it's not apparent from the photo, that's a fleur de lys in the middle of the blue shield.

It's heavier than I'd expected it to be.  Also, the little "balls" at the points of the heptagram suggest it was cast in a mold, since there is a line marking the two parts of the mold.  The back is closed and there is no makers mark/signature.  The enamel(?) on the red points of the heptagram is a pretty ruby red but is almost glass-like; one can see through it, and it is a bit darker at some points than others.

When I bought it, all I was told was that it's "old."  And "broken" (as though the latter weren't apparent).

Any thoughts?  I'm grateful for all help resolving this mystery!

[image]

Comment: [Two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleur-de-lis) [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_of_Empress_Eugenie).

Comment: Why do you say that the crown doesn't look French?  To me itlooks like a simplified heraldic version of a French royal crown from the 18th or 19th century.

Comment: @MAGolding I agree that the the symbols look French.  My confusion is based on the overall design mimicking the French cockade that arose early in the French Revolution, yet the presence of the crown suggests affinity to the monarch that was overthrown.  The symbols would seem to both support and oppose the monarch at the same time, which seems an unlikely combination.  That's why I question whether the piece is French at all or if I'm misreading things entirely.

Comment: @CuriousMonkey: France became an empire after the revolution as well, under Napoleon, and his successors; see my previous comment.